# change colour of animation in INPUT

Tags: html, css, css-animations

animation of particles forming text value

[image]

[image]

how can I **change** the **color** of the text to any **other color** than white?

I have attached the images of animation also showing the transformation.

I tried everything by adding `id` or `classes` again in `input`, `div` and everything else but I'm unable to see the change.

Actually this is cloned from github.Anyone can check and try.
https://github.com/iAmPriyam/Dequinox18

```css
.mu-hero-featured-area {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 60px 0 150px;
  width: 100%;
}

.mu-hero-featured-content {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.mu-hero-featured-content h1 {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.mu-hero-featured-content h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.mu-event-date-line {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.mu-event-counter-area {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -280px;
  width: 100%;
}

#mu-event-counter {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.mu-event-counter-block {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-family: latothin;
  color: white;
  margin: 10 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.mu-event-counter-block span {
  font-family: "neouthin";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-top: 60px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mu-hero-overlay">
  <div id="bubble">

  </div>

  <!-- Start hero featured area -->
  <canvas id="scene"></canvas>
  <input id="copy" type="hidden" value="HELLO" />

  <div class="mu-event-counter-area">
    <div id="mu-event-counter">

    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- End hero featured area -->

</div>
```

Comment: Screenshots are missing

Comment: Please provide a code snippet that work!

Comment: @johannchopin sorry. I don't know how to make that work. I'm new to this. please  kindly clone from Github and then give me a solution.

Comment: If you provide the javascript for the canvas then the demo will probably work.